# Desaparecer un botón después de completar un bucle con JavaScript y Php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Yo tengo un sistema de usuarios
$usuario == Director
y quiero eliminar un botón para los que no sean Directores, la cuestión es que este botón está dentro de un bucle y cuando le aplico el estilo solo desaparece el primer botón.

html y php

```
            <?php
            foreach($persona as $dato){   
            ?>
            <tr>
              <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->ID ?></td>
              <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_nombre." ". $dato-> estudianteEVPR_primerapellido ?></td>
              <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_correoelectronico ?></td>
            
              <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_telefono ?></td>
              <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_pais ?></td>
              <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVRP_Estado ?></td>
              <td scope="row"><a href="editarTutorias.php?codigo=<?php echo $dato->ID ?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="text-light me-1 bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Editar</a></td>
              <td scope="row" class="sectionEliminarDirector" ><a  onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de eliminar ?');" href="eliminarTutorias.php?codigo=<?php echo $dato->ID ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="text-light me-1 bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Eliminar</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
              }
            ?>
         </tbody>
```

Php y Javascript -la condicional si lee que el usuario logeado no es el director desaparece el boton a travez de la clase en 'sectionEliminarDirector'

```
<?php
if($usuario == 'Director'){
   echo '<script language="javascript">
         function aparecerBtn{
         buttonEliminar = document.getElementsByTag("sectionEliminarDirector");
         buttonEliminar.style.display = "";}
         window.onload = function() {aparecerBtn();};
         </script>';
} else {
  echo'<script language="javascript">
       function desaparecerDivEditar(){
       buttonEliminar = document.querySelector(".sectionEliminarDirector");
       buttonEliminar.style.display = "none";}
       window.onload = function() {desaparecerDivEditar();};
       </script>';
};?>
```

Captura (podrán ver que solo el primer botón de eliminar desaparece), gracias de antemano
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor sería que el botón aparezca solo si el usuario tiene los permisos necesarios para eliminar.

```
<?php
foreach($persona as $dato){   
?>
<tr>
  <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->ID ?></td>
  <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_nombre." ". $dato-> estudianteEVPR_primerapellido ?></td>
  <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_correoelectronico ?></td>

  <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_telefono ?></td>
  <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_pais ?></td>
  <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVRP_Estado ?></td>
  <td scope="row"><a href="editarTutorias.php?codigo=<?php echo $dato->ID ?>" class="btn btn-success"><i class="text-light me-1 bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Editar</a></td>
  <td scope="row" class="sectionEliminarDirector" >
<?php
    if($usuario == 'Director') {
        // Mostrar botón solo si el usuario es director
?>
    <a  onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de eliminar ?');" href="eliminarTutorias.php?codigo=<?php echo $dato->ID ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="text-light me-1 bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Eliminar</a>
<?php
    } // Fin del if de usuario
?>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Si todavía quieres hacerlo con Javascript, necesitas obtener todos los botones y recorrer para ocultar cada uno:

```
<?php
if($usuario == 'Director') {
   // Aquí no necesitas hacer cambios, el botón ya está visible
} else {
?>
    <script>
    // Obtener todos los botones por clase
    let delButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-danger');
    // Recorrer y ocultar
    delButtons.forEach(btn => btn.style.display = 'none');
    </script>
<?php
} // fin del if de usuario
?>
```

Insisto, la mejor opción es que desde PHP decidas si el botón se va a mostrar o no.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si tienes razón la forma mas optima es hacerlo con php, tu respuesta soluciono mi problema (: , éxitos!

Answer (score 1):

En el arreglo de `$persona,` deberias de obtener tambien el rol de esa persona, y dentro del foreach solo validas cuando `$dato->rolPersona == "Director"`  muestres el boton de eliminar.
Si el rol lo tienes en otra tabla deberias de hacer un JOIN con la tabla de roles.

```
  <?php
  foreach($persona as $dato){   
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->ID ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_nombre." ". $dato-> estudianteEVPR_primerapellido ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_correoelectronico ?></td>

    <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_telefono ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVPR_pais ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $dato->estudianteEVRP_Estado ?></td>
    <td scope="row">
      <a href="editarTutorias.php?codigo=<?php echo $dato->ID ?>" class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="text-light me-1 bi bi-pencil-square"></i> Editar</a>
      <?php 
        if($dato->rol == "Director" )  {
      ?>
        <a onclick="return confirm('¿Estás seguro de eliminar ?');" href="eliminarTutorias.php?codigo=<?php echo $dato->ID ?>" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="text-light me-1 bi bi-trash-fill"></i> Eliminar</a>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
      
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: si claro funciono poniendo la condicional adentro de la tabla, gracias por tu ayuda!